# Why is template type deduction failing here?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, condition-variable, type-deduction

Why in the following piece of code, does the template type cannot be deduced automatically from the last argument, like it does in `std::condition_variable::wait` ?

```
template< typename Predicate >
    //requires Truth< Predicate >
class lock_monitor_guard
{
public:
    lock_monitor_guard( std::mutex& mutex, std::condition_variable& monitor, Predicate predicate );
    ~lock_monitor_guard();

private:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock;
    std::condition_variable& monitor;
};

template< typename Predicate >
    //requires Truth< Predicate >
lock_monitor_guard<Predicate>::lock_monitor_guard( std::mutex& mutex, std::condition_variable& monitor, Predicate predicate )
    : lock( mutex ), monitor( monitor )
{
        monitor.wait<Predicate>( lock, predicate );
}

template< typename Predicate >
    //requires Truth< Predicate >
lock_monitor_guard<Predicate>::~lock_monitor_guard()
{
        lock.unlock();
        monitor.notify_one();
}
```

When I try to build a line like `lock_monitor_guard guard( jobs_mutex, jobs_monitor, ([]()->bool{return true;}) );`, I have an error message : `use of class template 'lock_monitor_guard' requires template arguments`.  But why ?  And why does it work with the STL `std::condition_variable::wait`.  Thank you for any help !

Comment: You have to give the template type for lock_monitor_guard.

Comment: Yes, but why ?  I don't want to guess the gruesome type of a lambda !  And why does `std::condition_variable::wait` differs ?

Comment: you can move `template< typename Predicate >` to make it a part of the constructor declaration, it will work then. the entire `lock_monitor_guard` class doesn't need to be parametrized with the type of `Predicate`

Comment: Very true piotr.  That's the best workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template arguments for types cannot be deduced, period.  This is because type specializations can provide a completely different set of members, so until you know the type's template arguments you don't even know what constructors are available.

This is why the standard library has helper functions, like `std::make_pair`.  When constructing or referring to an `std::pair` you *must* specify the type arguments (`std::pair<int, double>(1, 2.0)`) but in most cases they can be deduced when calling a function (`std::make_pair(1, 2.0)`).  (Note that `std::condition_variable::wait` is a function, not a type.)

If you implement a move constructor for your `lock_monitor_guard` type then you can create a helper function similar in spirit to `std::make_pair` and then use copy-initialization with `auto` to provide deduction.  (Note that you'll also have to tweak your destructor to account for the possibility that `this` had its contents "stolen" by the move constructor.)

```
template <typename Predicate>
lock_monitor_guard<Predicate> create_lock_monitor_guard(
    std::mutex & mutex,
    std::condition_variable & monitor,
    Predicate && predicate)
{
    return lock_monitor_guard<Predicate>(mutex, monitor, std::forward<Predicate>(predicate));
}

auto guard = create_lock_monitor_guard(
    jobs_mutex,
    jobs_monitor,
    [] { return true; });
```

Comment: Couldn't the compiler choose among all constructors of all possible specialization when the type is left to deduction ?

Comment: @Lærne Could the language be changed to allow that? Possibly. But the standard doesn't allow it, so it doesn't happen. Plus then you run into the case where someone introduces a new specialization and your code breaks or behaves differently because suddenly deduction is either ambiguous or results in choosing a different type than you intended. As it stands today, the type must be known before the constructors are inspected. In order to deduce, you'd need to have deduced already! Chicken and egg.

Comment: @Lærne Sure.  Provided you know how to write a compiler capable of evaluating an infinite number of possible instantiations in finite time and memory.

Comment: @James since there's finitely many written specialisation and constructors, there's finitely many checks to be done.  You don't need to actually evaluate all potential instantiations, just as many as there are different specialisation rules times as many constructors for a rule.  But I admit complexity can be an issue here.  cdhowie's issue of breaking code is also valid.  And personally I'll add that's a stupid idea because you could end up using an unspecialised template when there's a specialisation version available because you use a constructor only defined in the unspecialised template.

Comment: @Lærne The problem is that if you write something like `TemplateType( init_value )`, the compiler has to verify that for all possible instantiations of `TemplateType`, there is only one which can be constructed with `init_value`.  For simple cases, it's probable that this could be deduced (except that there may be explicit specializations), but in general, I don't think it can be solved in finite time or memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the type as shown below.

```
template< typename Predicate >
        //requires Truth< Predicate >
    class lock_monitor_guard
    {
    public:
        lock_monitor_guard( std::mutex& mutex, std::condition_variable& monitor, Predicate predicate );
    };


auto pred = [] { return true; };

lock_monitor_guard<decltype(pred)> l(jobs_mutex, jobs_monitor, pred);
```

And `std::condition_variable::wait` is function and not type hence the type is automatically deduced.